# How to navigate Chrome settings using `chromedp`?

Tags: go, chromedp

I'm trying to navigate the Chrome settings page using [`chromedp`](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp) in go.

The full example is [here](https://github.com/filmil/bugreports/tree/main/chromedp/settings), but the gist is something very basic and simple:

```golang
//...
if err := cdp.Run(ctx,
    cdp.Navigate(`chrome://settings/content/location`),
    cdp.SendKeys(`#input`, "hello"),
); err != nil && !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "net::ERR_ABORTED") {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
//...
```

Ostensibly, the settings page at `chrome://settings/content/location` has a DOM, and the
search field looks like an input field (with the ID `#input`).  And yet, trying to interact with it through `chromedp` fails: `chromedp` does not seem to find it at all.

For some background, I am trying to configure some aspects of Chrome, namely automatically denying location requests, which do not seem to have a command line flag. Or at least I was not able to find one.  My example above interacts with the input field
because it seem it would be easier to select.

What I really want is to click on the radio button which says "don't allow websites to see your location".  Similar to the input field above, I can not figure out the correct incantation that will cause `chromedp` to select a specific radio button. If there is an alternative way to achieve this, I'm all ears. I would, however, like to avoid needing a pre-populated userdir if possible.  I'm new to `chromedp` so I apologize if this is something trivial. Yet, I couldn't find an answer.  There is a [similar question about selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376486/navigate-to-settings-page-of-chrome-using-selenium), but I think `chromedp` may be sufficiently different that the answer may be different too.

Answer (score 0):

You can not find the element because it's a shadow element. With chromedp, you can search shadow elements with `chromedp.ByJSPath`. Here is an example copied from https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/1050#issuecomment-1085474910:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate("chrome://settings/handlers"),
        chromedp.Click(`document.querySelector("body > settings-ui").shadowRoot.querySelector("#main").shadowRoot.querySelector("settings-basic-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#basicPage > settings-section > settings-privacy-page").shadowRoot.querySelector("#pages > settings-subpage > protocol-handlers").shadowRoot.querySelector("#protcolHandlersRadioBlock")`, chromedp.ByJSPath),
    ); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```